# Gcloud app deploy npm install package fetch failed

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I'm using Google App Engine with parse-server.

Locally, npm install and npm start work fine but when I try to deploy on app engine I get this error :

```
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/intersect/-/intersect-1.0.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 502
npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-61-generic
npm ERR! argv "/nodejs/bin/node" "/nodejs/bin/npm" "install" "--unsafe-perm"
npm ERR! node v4.3.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read
```

when I try to go to https://registry.npmjs.org/intersect/-/intersect-1.0.1.tgz it downloads the package just fine on my computer.

Can I fix this from my side or is this totally on google's side ?

Answer (score 1):

check out https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/13284 , seems to be an issue npm is aware of and are in the process of fixing